# Nested Do and Do while Fortran loops

Tags: loops, fortran, do-while

I'm writing this small program that stores grades in an array and then averages them. The program is supposed to accept up to 10 grades and stop and only accept grades that are > 0 and < 100. Here is my code:

```
  program Average
  implicit none 
  character(len = 50) f_name, l_name 
  integer i, j, amtOfGrades
  real grade, arraySum, avg
  
  Real, Dimension(10)::a
  
  do i = 1, 10
        if(.not. (j .LE. 100 .AND. j .GE. 0)) then
              write(*,*)'Enter grade: '
              read(*,*)a(i)
              j = a(i)
              arraySum = sum(a)
              avg = arraySum/10
        else
              avg = arraySum/(i-1)
        end if
  end do
```

The problem I'm having is with the nested loop section. I cannot get the two conditions I need to work together, which are only up to 10 grades (what the DO is for) AND only accepting grades that in the range of 0-100 (what the DO WHILE is for).

Comment: Why do you think this is not working? (It is definitely wrong in that you don't define `temp` and `j` before referencing them in the while conditions, or `i` before it's used in the read statement.) Please show expected and observed behaviours and any compiler messages.

Comment: other problems aside, consider that your inner loop you probably want to loop while the value is OUTSIDE the valid range. If within the valid range, it can stop and continue counting to 10.

Comment: @francescalus I just realized I posted the wrong version, I just updated the post. So what is happening is that it is stopping the loop when the grade is not in range (0-100) but the outer do (which is supposed to iterate 10 times) is not. I can infinitely enter grades until one is not in range when I should only be able to enter 10.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I just updated the post with the right version of my program. Thank you for the tip, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Remove inner loop, it is completely wrong, and completely unnecessary. To terminate external loop prematurely, use: `if() exit`

Comment: @Serge3leo Its completely unnecessary? But how will I stop accepting grades when the grade entered is out of the bounds 0-100?

Comment: Simple use `if(.not. (j .LE. 100 .AND. j .GE. 0)) exit` for leave external loop.

Comment: @Serge3leo Okay, I added that. Now I have: if(.not. (j .LE. 100 .AND. j .GE. 0)) inside of do i = 1, 10. Is that correct? I am very new to fortran, I apologize but appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see any changes fortran code. I don't know. But, calculation of average value is also not correct, you need: `if(j .LE. 100 .AND. j .GE. 0) then ; avg = arraySum/10 ; else ; avg = arraySum/(i-1) ; endif` (divide zero by zero and print NaN, if not valid input value)

Comment: @Serge3leo I have edit the post with the new code. It doesn't seem to want to accept any input

Comment: There may well be other problems, but this is definitely wrong as you are still using variables before you have given them a value - for instance `j` and you are performing `sum( a )` before you have initialised all elements of a.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this will depend on what you want to do if an input grade is not `0 <= grade <= 100`. Does such an input count towards the limit of 10 grades?

If a bad input does count towards the limit, then you will only need to `read` from the user 10 times, but you might end up with less than 10 grades total. So you will need to keep track of how many grades have been entered.

Code for this might look like:

```
program average
  implicit none
  
  integer :: i, amtOfGrades
  real :: grade, arraySum, avg
  real, dimension(10) :: a
  
  amtOfGrades = 0
  do i=1,10
    write(*,*) 'Enter grade: '
    read(*,*) grade
    if (0<=grade .and. grade<=100) then
      amtOfGrades = amtOfGrades + 1
      array(amtOfGrades) = grade
    endif
  end do
  
  arraySum = sum(a(:amtOfGrades))
  avg = arraySum/amtOfGrades
end program
```

If instead a bad input does not count towards the limit then you will always end up with 10 grades, but you might have to `read` from the user an infinite number of times.

Code for this might look like:

```
program average
  implicit none
  
  integer :: i
  real :: grade, arraySum, avg
  real, dimension(10) :: a
  
  do i=1,10
    do
      write(*,*) 'Enter grade: '
      read(*,*) grade
      if (0<=grade .and. grade<=100) then
        array(i) = grade
        exit
      endif
    enddo
  end do
  
  arraySum = sum(a)
  avg = arraySum/10
end program
```

Comment: Why use double precision for grades? Do you really want to see results of 91.999999997 displayed? A `real` would suffice just as the _op_ has.

Answer (score 1):

You need to issue an `exit` statement to quit the loop before the max of 10 grades is entered:

```
program Console1
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none

! Variables
integer, parameter :: maxcount = 10
real :: a(maxcount), ave
integer :: i, count
count = 0
do i = 1, maxcount
    write(*,*) 'Enter grade: '
    read(*,*) a(i)
    if( a(i)<=0.0 .or. a(i)>=100.0) then
        exit
    end if
    count = count + 1
end do

ave = sum(a)/count
write(*,*) 'The average is: ', ave

end program Console1
```

If you look in help you will see

> The EXIT statement causes execution of a DO loop or a named construct to be terminated.